# Debugging an Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I received an Excel document that is supposed to run a macro, but keep getting the following error:

Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument

I'm trying to follow the Microsoft docs but am pretty stumped on what is throwing the error.

```
If IsDate(Left(Sheets("Unit RPAM").Cells(RowCount, 1), 10)) Then
            Cells(WriteRow, 6) = Left(Sheets("Unit RPAM").Cells(RowCount, 1), 10)
           
            RPAMDateString = Sheets("Unit RPAM").Cells(RowCount, 1)
            'RPAMDate Format: 2016/12/18 2017/12/17 B1 32 15 0 0 15 V 62 62 01/00/00
           
            StringIndex = 12 'Next non-space character
            For WriteCol = 7 To 16
                WriteString = ""    'Resets string to blank to keep collection of all non-space characters
                           
                Do                  'Loop adds each character to WriteString until encountering a space
                    WriteString = WriteString + Mid(RPAMDateString, StringIndex, 1)
                    StringIndex = StringIndex + 1
               Loop While Mid(RPAMDateString, StringIndex, 1) <> " " '<<<the problem
               
                Cells(WriteRow, WriteCol) = WriteString
                StringIndex = StringIndex + 1
            Next WriteCol
           
            Cells(WriteRow, 17) = Right(Sheets("Unit RPAM").Cells(RowCount, 1), 8)
            WriteRow = WriteRow + 1
        End If
```

Comment: You'll need to look at the variables used in that line, and figure out which of them is the one causing the problem.  Probably also worth checking for missing references in the VB project.

Comment: When it fails what are the values of `RPAMDateString` and `Stringindex` ?

Comment: _You passed an invalid parameter in your procedure call. This could be because the parameter was out of range, or contained invalid data. Alternately, you may have invoked a procedure at an unexpected time.
 **To correct this error** - 1/ Verify that the parameters being passed to the procedure are valid.  2/ Verify that you are calling the function at an appropriate time._ From Help

Comment: I've just tried it and it works fine!